# vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines understanding

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

It would be a very basic question but I can't understand. I'm reading about the integration of kotlin coroutines with Vertx platform ([here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-lang-kotlin-coroutines/kotlin/#_awaiting_the_completion_of_vert_x_asynchronous_results)) and come across the below code snippet.

```
val vertx = Vertx.vertx()

GlobalScope.launch(vertx.dispatcher()) {
  val timerId = awaitEvent<Long> { handler ->
    vertx.setTimer(1000, handler)
  }
  println("Event fired from timer with id $timerId")
}
```

and it's the definition from the page

> The vertx.dispatcher() returns a coroutine dispatcher that execute
> coroutines using the Vert.x event loop.
>
> The awaitEvent function suspends the execution of the coroutine until
> the timer fires and resumes the coroutines with the value that was
> given to the handler.
>
> More details are given in the next sections on handlers, events and
> stream of events.

Now my question is whats the purpose of the `handler` and what it's type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many asynchronous operations in Vert.x take a `Handler<T>` as the last argument. `vertx.setTimer()` is one of such asynchronous functions, it calls `handler` when the timer fires. According to the [docs of `Vertx.setTimer()` method](https://vertx.io/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.reactivex.core/-vertx/set-timer.html) it accepts `handler: Handler<Long>` as the second parameter. We can conclude that generic type of `Handler<T>` is `Long`.

Suspend function [`awaitEvent`](https://vertx.io/preview/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines/await-event.html) takes lambda block as the parameter, which in turn receives parameter of type `Handler<T>`. According to the [docs](https://vertx.io/preview/docs/kdoc/vertx/io.vertx.kotlin.coroutines/await-event.html):

> The block is executed with a `Handler<T>` argument that shall be called once.
> When the handler is called, `awaitEvent` returns the value that the handler received.

So when passing `handler` to `vertx.setTimer(1000, handler)` function, it calls `handler` after the delay (1000 milliseconds) is elapsed and `awaitEvent` function in turn returns the value received by the handler (timer ID).